# How can i make object to rotate smooth towards a target with raycast?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have object that move around in fixed radius around another object with random height.

In this script i want the transform(turret) to rotate facing the target(target is the object that move with the random height) and that the laser that shoot will hit all the time the moving around target.

In the original i used the mouse to rotate the transform to be facing objects but now i want that the transform will rotate automatic to the moving target with the laser.

I added this part to the script and the laser start when running the game but the transform is not rotating facing the target. and i still can rotate the transform with the mouse and in this case i don't want the mouse to rotate the transform but that the transform will be rotating automatic.

```
if (startLaser)
        {
            Destroy(Instance);
            Instance = Instantiate(Prefabs[Prefab], FirePoint.transform.position, FirePoint.transform.rotation);
            Instance.transform.parent = transform;
            LaserScript = Instance.GetComponent<Hovl_Laser>();
            LaserScript2 = Instance.GetComponent<Hovl_Laser2>();

            startLaser = false;
        }

        if (Cam != null)
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            RayMouse = Cam.ScreenPointToRay(target.position);
            if(Physics.Raycast(RayMouse.origin, RayMouse.direction, out hit, MaxLength))
            {
                RotateToMouseDirection(gameObject, hit.point);
            }
            else
            {
                var pos = RayMouse.GetPoint(MaxLength);
                RotateToMouseDirection(gameObject, pos);
            }
        }
```

but it's not working the transform is not rotating automatic and the mouse still controlling the rotating.

This is the full script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters;
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class Hovl_DemoLasers : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public GameObject FirePoint;
    public Camera Cam;
    public float MaxLength;
    public GameObject[] Prefabs;

    private Ray RayMouse;
    private Vector3 direction;
    private Quaternion rotation;

    [Header("GUI")]
    private float windowDpi;

    private int Prefab;
    private GameObject Instance;
    private Hovl_Laser LaserScript;
    private Hovl_Laser2 LaserScript2;

    private bool rotateMouse = true;
    private bool startLaser = true;

    //Double-click protection
    private float buttonSaver = 0f;

    void Start ()
    {
        if (Screen.dpi < 1) windowDpi = 1;
        if (Screen.dpi < 200) windowDpi = 1;
        else windowDpi = Screen.dpi / 200f;
        Counter(0);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Enable lazer
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Destroy(Instance);
            Instance = Instantiate(Prefabs[Prefab], FirePoint.transform.position, FirePoint.transform.rotation);
            Instance.transform.parent = transform;
            LaserScript = Instance.GetComponent<Hovl_Laser>();
            LaserScript2 = Instance.GetComponent<Hovl_Laser2>();

            rotateMouse = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            rotateMouse = false;
        }

        //To change lazers
        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0) && buttonSaver >= 0.4f)// left button
        {
            buttonSaver = 0f;
            Counter(-1);
        }
        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0) && buttonSaver >= 0.4f)// right button
        {
            buttonSaver = 0f;
            Counter(+1);         
        }
        buttonSaver += Time.deltaTime;

        if (startLaser)
        {
            Destroy(Instance);
            Instance = Instantiate(Prefabs[Prefab], FirePoint.transform.position, FirePoint.transform.rotation);
            Instance.transform.parent = transform;
            LaserScript = Instance.GetComponent<Hovl_Laser>();
            LaserScript2 = Instance.GetComponent<Hovl_Laser2>();

            startLaser = false;
        }

        if (Cam != null)
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            RayMouse = Cam.ScreenPointToRay(target.position);
            if(Physics.Raycast(RayMouse.origin, RayMouse.direction, out hit, MaxLength))
            {
                RotateToMouseDirection(gameObject, hit.point);
            }
            else
            {
                var pos = RayMouse.GetPoint(MaxLength);
                RotateToMouseDirection(gameObject, pos);
            }
        }

        //Current fire point
        if (Cam != null && rotateMouse)
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            var mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            RayMouse = Cam.ScreenPointToRay(mousePos);
            
            if (Physics.Raycast(RayMouse.origin, RayMouse.direction, out hit, MaxLength))
            {
                RotateToMouseDirection(gameObject, hit.point);

            }
            else
            {
                var pos = RayMouse.GetPoint(MaxLength);
                RotateToMouseDirection(gameObject, pos);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("No camera");
        }
    }

    //GUI Text
    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10 * windowDpi, 5 * windowDpi, 400 * windowDpi, 20 * windowDpi), "Use the keyboard buttons A/<- and D/-> to change lazers!");
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10 * windowDpi, 20 * windowDpi, 400 * windowDpi, 20 * windowDpi), "Use left mouse button for shooting!");
    }

    //To change prefabs (count - prefab number)
    void Counter(int count)
    {
        Prefab += count;
        if (Prefab > Prefabs.Length - 1)
        {
            Prefab = 0;
        }
        else if (Prefab < 0)
        {
            Prefab = Prefabs.Length - 1;
        }
    }
  
    //To rotate fire point
    void RotateToMouseDirection (GameObject obj, Vector3 destination)
    {
        direction = destination - obj.transform.position;
        rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);     
        obj.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(obj.transform.rotation, rotation, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine : I'm not sure if i need to use the out hit variable in the Automatic aiming part ? do i need to use the hit variable and if so how ?

```
// Automatic aiming part
            if (Cam != null)
            {
                RaycastHit hit;
     
                if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, MaxLength))
                {
                    RotateToMouseDirection(gameObject, target.position);
                }
            }
```

Anyway it's not working as i wanted.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters;
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class Hovl_DemoLasers : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public GameObject FirePoint;
    public Camera Cam;
    public float MaxLength;
    public GameObject[] Prefabs;

    private Ray RayMouse;
    private Ray AutomaticRay;
    private Vector3 direction;
    private Quaternion rotation;

    [Header("GUI")]
    private float windowDpi;

    private int Prefab;
    private GameObject Instance;
    private Hovl_Laser LaserScript;
    private Hovl_Laser2 LaserScript2;

    private bool rotateMouse = true;
    private bool startLaser = true;

    //Double-click protection
    private float buttonSaver = 0f;

    void Start ()
    {
        //LaserEndPoint = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        if (Screen.dpi < 1) windowDpi = 1;
        if (Screen.dpi < 200) windowDpi = 1;
        else windowDpi = Screen.dpi / 200f;
        Counter(0);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //Enable lazer
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Destroy(Instance);
            Instance = Instantiate(Prefabs[Prefab], FirePoint.transform.position, FirePoint.transform.rotation);
            Instance.transform.parent = transform;
            LaserScript = Instance.GetComponent<Hovl_Laser>();
            LaserScript2 = Instance.GetComponent<Hovl_Laser2>();

            rotateMouse = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            rotateMouse = false;
        }

            //Disable lazer prefab
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            /*if (LaserScript) LaserScript.DisablePrepare();
            if (LaserScript2) LaserScript2.DisablePrepare();
            Destroy(Instance,1);*/
        }

        //To change lazers
        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0) && buttonSaver >= 0.4f)// left button
        {
            buttonSaver = 0f;
            Counter(-1);
        }
        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) || Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0) && buttonSaver >= 0.4f)// right button
        {
            buttonSaver = 0f;
            Counter(+1);         
        }
        buttonSaver += Time.deltaTime;

        if (startLaser)
        {
            rotateMouse = false;

            Destroy(Instance);
            Instance = Instantiate(Prefabs[Prefab], FirePoint.transform.position, FirePoint.transform.rotation);
            Instance.transform.parent = transform;
            LaserScript = Instance.GetComponent<Hovl_Laser>();
            LaserScript2 = Instance.GetComponent<Hovl_Laser2>();

            startLaser = false;
        }


        // Automatic aiming part
        if (Cam != null)
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
 
            if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out hit, MaxLength))
            {
                RotateToMouseDirection(gameObject, target.position);
            }
        }

        //Current fire point
        if (Cam != null && rotateMouse)
        {
            RaycastHit hit; //DELATE THIS IF YOU WANT TO USE LASERS IN 2D
            var mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
            RayMouse = Cam.ScreenPointToRay(mousePos);
            //ADD THIS IF YOU WANT TO USE LASERS IN 2D: RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(RayMouse.origin, RayMouse.direction, MaxLength);
            if (Physics.Raycast(RayMouse.origin, RayMouse.direction, out hit, MaxLength)) //CHANGE THIS IF YOU WANT TO USE LASERRS IN 2D: if (hit.collider != null)
            {
                RotateToMouseDirection(gameObject, hit.point);
            }
            else
            {
                var pos = RayMouse.GetPoint(MaxLength);
                RotateToMouseDirection(gameObject, pos);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("No camera");
        }
    }

    //GUI Text
    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10 * windowDpi, 5 * windowDpi, 400 * windowDpi, 20 * windowDpi), "Use the keyboard buttons A/<- and D/-> to change lazers!");
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10 * windowDpi, 20 * windowDpi, 400 * windowDpi, 20 * windowDpi), "Use left mouse button for shooting!");
    }

    //To change prefabs (count - prefab number)
    void Counter(int count)
    {
        Prefab += count;
        if (Prefab > Prefabs.Length - 1)
        {
            Prefab = 0;
        }
        else if (Prefab < 0)
        {
            Prefab = Prefabs.Length - 1;
        }
    }
  
    //To rotate fire point
    void RotateToMouseDirection (GameObject obj, Vector3 destination)
    {
        direction = destination - obj.transform.position;
        rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);     
        obj.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(obj.transform.rotation, rotation, 1);
    }
}
```